# SQLSTATE [08001] Microsoft ODBC Driver 18 for SQL Server SSL Provider: The certificate chain was issued by an authority that is not trusted

Tags: php, sql-server, sql-server-2019

Soy primerizo en esto, actualmente estaba realizando un desarrollo con IIS Express conectando a una BD en un servidor externo con Microsoft SQL Server 2019, no había tenido ningún problema, hasta que traté de montar la página en Windows Server.

El error que me manda es el siguiente a pesar de que el sitio ya cuenta con un certificado SSL.

> Array ( [0] => Array ( [0] => 08001 [SQLSTATE] => 08001 [1] => -2146893019 [code] => -2146893019 [2] => [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 18 for SQL Server]SSL Provider: The certificate chain was issued by an authority that is not trusted.[message] => [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 18 for SQL Server]SSL
> Provider: The certificate chain was issued by an authority that is not trusted.)
> [1] => Array ([0] => 08001[SQLSTATE] => 08001[1] => -2146893019[code] => -2146893019             [2] => [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 18 for SQL Server]Client unable to establish connection[message] => [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 18 for SQL Server]Client unable to establish connection))

Quiero creer que el problema es con la manera en que manejo la configuración que empleo para la conexión a la base de datos, que es la siguiente.

```
<?php
   $serverName = "//serverName\instanceName";
   $connectionInfo = array( "Database"=>"Database", "UID"=>"UID","PWD"=>"PWD");
   $connection = sqlsrv_connect( $serverName, $connectionInfo);

   if( !$connection ) {
     die(print_r( sqlsrv_errors(), true));
   }

?>
```

Comment: Versión de SQL server?

Comment: Solo sé que es Microsoft SQL Server 2019, la versión especifica no la he consultado.

Comment: Prueba en el connection info poner un parámetro adicional `encrypt` con valor `false`. Con esto desactivas el cifrado. Lo otro sería que pongas un certificado válido en el servidor

Comment: El mensaje indica que estarías usando para la conexión un certificado emitido por una entidad que no es reconocida como una fuente de confianza. [Revisa la documentación al respecto](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/troubleshoot/sql/connect/error-message-when-you-connect).

Answer (score 2):

Prueba instalando [SQL Server Managment Studio](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ssms/download-sql-server-management-studio-ssms?view=sql-server-ver16), yo tenia un problema similar, hice una API con PHP 7, en la maquina de desarrollo funciono sin problemas pero en mi caso yo estaba utilizando la librería (**pdo_sqlsrv**)

La idea era montar la API en un servidor y por seguridad la base de datos en otro y al hacer pruebas me marcaba exactamente el mismo error cuando trataba de conectarme al servidor donde estaba la base de datos.

Después de estar navegando solo encontraba la solución de el `encrypt=false` pero no me funcionaba. Al parecer al servidor le hacían falta algunas librerías de ODBC que se instalan con **SQL Server Managment Studio**

Esto me funciono y no hubo necesidad de modificar código, ojala te funcione

Comment: Tal y como está redactada, tu respuesta no es clara. Por favor, pulsa en [edit] para añadir detalles adicionales que ayuden a los demás a entender cómo esto responde a la pregunta formulada. Puedes encontrar más información sobre cómo escribir buenas respuestas [en el centro de ayuda](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

***Al parecer el error esta documentado [aqui](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/troubleshoot/sql/connect/error-message-when-you-connect) por la misma microsoft.***

***Y lo que se indica en la solucion es lo siguiente (Traduccion):***

Si usa intencionalmente un certificado de una autoridad que no es de confianza o un certificado autofirmado para cifrar las conexiones a SQL Server, puede usar una de las siguientes opciones:

Para el escenario 1: agregue la entidad emisora ​​de certificados al almacén de entidades emisoras de certificados raíz de confianza en el equipo cliente que inicia la conexión cifrada. Para hacer esto, complete Exportar el certificado del servidor e Instalar la autoridad de certificación raíz (CA) en los procedimientos de la máquina cliente que se enumeran a continuación en esa secuencia.

Exportar el certificado del servidor
El ejemplo utiliza un archivo denominado caCert.cer como archivo de certificado. Debe obtener este archivo de certificado del servidor. Los siguientes pasos explican cómo exportar el certificado del servidor a un archivo:

1. Haga clic en Inicio y luego en Ejecutar y escriba MMC. (MMC es un
   acrónimo de Microsoft Management Console).
2. En MMC, abra los Certificados.
3. Expanda Personal y luego Certificados.
4. Haga clic con el botón derecho en el certificado del servidor y
   luego seleccione Todas las tareas->Exportar.
5. Haga clic en Siguiente para pasar del cuadro de diálogo de
   bienvenida del Asistente para exportación de certificados.
6. Confirme que No, no exportar la clave privada esté seleccionado y
   luego haga clic en Siguiente.
7. Asegúrese de que esté seleccionado X.509 binario codificado en DER
   (.CER) o X.509 (.CER) codificado en Base-64 y luego haga clic en
   Siguiente.
8. Introduzca un nombre de archivo de exportación.
9. Haga clic en Siguiente y luego en Finalizar para exportar el
   certificado.

Instale la autoridad de certificación raíz (CA) en la máquina cliente

1. Inicie el complemento Certificados para MMC en el equipo cliente y luego agregue el complemento Certificados.
2. En el cuadro de diálogo Complemento de certificados, seleccione Cuenta de  quipo y, a continuación, seleccione Siguiente.
3. En el panel Seleccionar equipo, elija Equipo local: (el equipo en el que se ejecuta esta consola) y luego seleccione Finalizar.
4. Elija Aceptar para cerrar el cuadro de diálogo Agregar o quitar complementos.
5. En el panel izquierdo de MMC, expanda el nodo Certificados (equipo local).
6. Expanda el nodo Autoridades de certificación raíz de confianza, haga clic con el botón derecho en la subcarpeta Certificados, seleccione Todas las tareas y luego elija Importar.
7. En el Asistente de importación de certificados, en la página de bienvenida, elija Siguiente.
8. En la página Archivo para importar, elija Examinar.
9. Busque la ubicación del archivo de certificado caCert.cer, seleccione el archivo y luego elija Abrir.
10. En la página Archivo para importar, elija Siguiente.
11. En la página de almacenamiento de certificados, acepte la selección predeterminada y luego elija Siguiente.
12. En la página Finalización del asistente de importación de certificados, elija Finalizar.

Para los escenarios 1 y 2: Establezca la configuración del Certificado de servidor de confianza en verdadero en su aplicación cliente.

Para obtener más información sobre cómo hacer esto, revise los siguientes temas:

[Uso de cifrado sin validación en SQL Server Native Client](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/native-client/features/using-encryption-without-validation?view=sql-server-ver16)

[Conexión con cifrado mediante el controlador JDBC de Microsoft para SQL Server](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/jdbc/connecting-with-ssl-encryption?view=sql-server-ver16)

[Uso de cifrado con Sqlclient](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/ado-net/sql/sqlclient-support-always-encrypted?view=sql-server-ver16)

***Precaución:***

Las conexiones SSL cifradas mediante un certificado autofirmado no brindan una seguridad sólida. Son susceptibles a ataques man-in-the-middle. No debe confiar en SSL usando certificados autofirmados en un entorno de producción o en servidores que están conectados a Internet.

Si la configuración discutida en las secciones anteriores de este artículo no es la deseada, puede usar una de las siguientes opciones para resolver este problema:

- Configure el motor de base de datos para usar el cifrado según el
  procedimiento en Habilitar conexiones cifradas al motor de base de
  datos.
- Si no se requiere cifrado:

  - Deshabilite la configuración de cifrado (si corresponde) en su aplicación cliente.
  - Deshabilite el cifrado del lado del servidor mediante el administrador de configuración de SQL Server. Para obtener más información sobre cómo hacerlo, consulte Configurar servidor.